# Maxlength и его перечисление

Tags: jquery, javascript

Вопрос такой. **Как перечислить атрибут maxlength?**
У меня три элемента формы.

```
//<input maxlength='100' />
//<textarea maxlength='255'></textarea>
//<textarea maxlength='500'></textarea>
```

> что вы имеете в виду под "перечислить атрибут"? Опишите подробнее, чего вы хотели добиться и что не получилось.

```
var maxLength = $('#title_book').attr('maxlength');
```

Получаем атрибут `input`.
Но я хочу получить атрибут не только `input`, но и других.. Через `for`..
А потом просто сделать при событие..

```
$(elem).val($(elem).val().substr(0, maxLength[i]));или
$(elem).val($(elem).val().substr(0, maxLength+i))
```

Иначе надо будет прописывать каждому элементу свое событие,так как атрибут то у них разные.То есть я сделал

```
$(elem).val($(elem).val().substr(0, maxLength1));
$(elem).val($(elem).val().substr(0, maxLength2));
$(elem).val($(elem).val().substr(0, maxLength3));
```

А я пытаюсь объединить в один..

Comment: @El_ten, что вы имеете в виду под "перечислить"? Опишите подробнее, чего вы хотели добиться и что не получилось.

Comment: var maxLength = $('#title_book').attr('maxlength'); 
Получаем атрибут input.
Но я хочу получить атрибут не только input,но и других..Через for..
А потом просто сделать при событие..
$(elem).val($(elem).val().substr(0, maxLength[i]));или
$(elem).val($(elem).val().substr(0, maxLength+i))
Иначе надо будет прописывать каждому элементу свое событие,так как атрибут то у них разные.То есть я сделал
$(elem).val($(elem).val().substr(0, maxLength1));
$(elem).val($(elem).val().substr(0, maxLength2));
$(elem).val($(elem).val().substr(0, maxLength3));

А я пытаюсь объединить в один..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var maxLength = [];
$("[maxlength]").each(function () {
    maxLength.push($(this).attr('maxlength'))
});
// ["100", "255", "500"]
```

Answer (score 1):

как-то так (ответ на вопрос в комментарии):

```
$(document).on('ваше событие','[maxlength]', function(){
  var ml = parseInt($(this).attr('maxlength'));
  $(this).val($(this).val().substr(0,ml));
});
```